# How to organize bets/prizes in a game with ranked results?

Tags: algorithm, math, multiplayer, gambling

## Problem

I'm making a multiplayer game with bets where players end up ranked by their final score. I want to figure out how much money do they win/lose in the end based on:

1. their ranking/score;
2. size of their bet.

## Example

There was a game with 5 players, and it ended like this:

```
1. Ben, score 2115, bet 100
2. Jim, score 1856, bet 250
3. Lenny, score 1512, bet 30
4. Martha, score 1220, bet 70
5. Richard, score 987, bet 50
```

### Thoughts

Now, how do I decide who gets how much money? The only thing that's obvious for me is that player #1 should at least get their bet back so they don't lose.

I can't even tell that in a critical case of 2 players, the whole bet of 2nd ranked player goes to the winner.

Why I want the size of bets to be considered is to not make it possible that a player who bets 1 coin plays against another player who bets 100 coins and thus risks only 1 coin while their potential prize is 100. That's unfair to the player who bets 100 coins because they risk 100 times more than they can gain. I'm afraid of potential abuse.

Another questionable situation that is theoretically possible is that players end up with the same score. With no or equal bets, we could just consider it a draw, but what if players made different bets? They were in unequal conditions, had unequal risk, but achieved same result, so isn't it a win for one of them?

### Possible solutions

I was thinking of an option to make "top half" of players winners, "bottom half" losers, and a possible middle player a drawer. Then, in the above game, Lenny is a drawer and gets his bet of 30 back, not losing and not gaining. Martha and Richard lose their bets and this total of 120 gets split between winners Ben and Jim. But there are some problems:

- Ben ranked #1 and that gives a reason to give him more, but Jim made 2.5x higher bet while his score is only ~10% lower than Jim's. Who should get more, Ben or Jim?
- What if both Richard and Martha would only bet 1 coin, or even 0? That puts both Ben and Jim into an unfair situation when their risk is way higher than their potential gain.

I tried to look into betting systems in other games, like poker, roulette, horse racing, but nothing exactly matches this situation.

In the worst case, I might consider awarding players from "the house" instead of what other players lost. But I would like to keep it as a game between players, not against the house.

**P.S.** Sorry if the question isn't exactly fit for Stack Overflow. In my view, it's actually a programming question about an algorithm/formula to handle specific data. I will consider asking elsewhere if I get a good suggestion where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the top bet with the bottom bet.  Repeat.

In the case of ties, pool their bets, figure out how much the group wins or loses, then divide that proportionately to how much they gave.  (If it comes out uneven, randomly choose who gains/loses the last point.)

So in your example we would do this:

```
1. Ben, score 2115, bet 100
2. Jim, score 1856, bet 250
3. Lenny, score 1512, bet 30
4. Martha, score 1220, bet 70
5. Richard, score 987, bet 50
```

Match `Ben` with `Richard`.  `Ben` wins 50, `Richard` drops out.

```
1. Ben, score 2115, bet 50
2. Jim, score 1856, bet 250
3. Lenny, score 1512, bet 30
4. Martha, score 1220, bet 70
```

Match `Ben` with `Martha`.  `Ben` wins 50 and drops out.

```
1. Jim, score 1856, bet 250
2. Lenny, score 1512, bet 30
3. Martha, score 1220, bet 20
```

Match `Jim` with `Martha`.  `Jim` wins 20 and `Martha` drops out.

```
1. Jim, score 1856, bet 230
2. Lenny, score 1512, bet 30
```

Match `Jim` with `Lenny`.  `Jim` wins 30 and `Lenny` drops out.

```
1. Jim, score 1856, bet 200
```

We are done.  The final division of the rewards is:

```
1. Ben, score 2115, has 200
2. Jim, score 1856, has 300
3. Lenny, score 1512, has 0
4. Martha, score 1220, has 0
5. Richard, score 987, has 0
```

And now winnings generally go to the top half.  And nobody stands to gain or lose more than they put up.

Comment: I really like it and probably I will use it if nothing else appears. The only downside I can see is that gain is limited to the double bet. Is there possibly a way to adjust how rewarding it can be?

Comment: @Helyrk When you match top and bottom, how many loser points match to each winning point?  If you made it a 2-1 ratio then people can triple their bet (and more lose).  You could even make the ratio vary from game to game.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation on "top half" winners and "bottom half" losers (with "middle" as a draw). The money bet by the losers is the pot.

Take the smallest winning bet, and multiply by the number of winners. If that amount is more than is in the pot, then the amount is whatever is in the pot. Now split that amount amongst the winners in proportion to their score. Remove the player that had the smallest bet. Repeat.

If there's still money in the pot, that money is split amongst the losers in proportion to their bets.

Example:

```
name:   Ben  Jim  Len  Mar  Ric
bets:   100  250   30   70   50
score: 2115 1856 1512 1220  987

pot: 120
minimum winning bet times number of winners: 100 * 2 = 200
amount to split: 120 (since 120<200)
Ben gets 120 * 2115 / (2115+1856) = 64
Jim gets 120 * 1856 / (2115+1856) = 56

Cash after the game is finished:
name:   Ben  Jim  Len  Mar  Ric
cash:   164  306   30    0    0
```

Example 2:

```
name:   Ben  Jim   Lu    Tim  Mar Ric 
bets:   100  250   10    120  200  80
score: 2115 1856 1512   1220  987 642

pot: 400
minimum winning bet times number of winners: 10 * 3 = 30
winners total score: 2115+1856+1512 = 5483
Ben gets 30 * 2115/5483 = 12
Jim gets 30 * 1856/5483 = 10
Lu  gets 30 * 1512/5483 =  8
remove 10 from each winning bet, Lu is done

remaining pot: 370
minimum winning bet times number of winners: 90 * 2 = 180
winners total score = 2115+1856 = 3971
Ben gets 180 * 2115/3971 = 96
Jim gets 180 * 1856/3971 = 84
remove 90 from each winning bet, Ben is done

remaining pot: 190
minimum winning bet times number of winners: 150 * 1 = 150
Jim gets 150

remaining pot: 40
total bets by the losers: 400
Tim gets 40 * 120/400 = 12
Mar gets 40 * 200/400 = 20
Ric gets 40 *  80/400 =  8

Cash after the game is finished:
name:   Ben  Jim   Lu    Tim  Mar Ric 
cash:   208  494   18     12   20   8
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a good solution but I can't use it because it doesn't take into account sizes of bets. It can possibly create a very unfair situation when players can, essentially, rob each other.

Comment: @Helyrk It very definitely takes into account the size of the bets. For example, Lu only bet 10, so her payout was only 18. Kindly give an example of a situation where the players rob each other.

Comment: With the other answer, if Jim had the highest score, he would take everybody's money (only one winner). On the other hand, if Jim had the lowest score, he would pay everybody (only one loser).

Comment: I reviewed your answer again and figured that I was wrong about the situation with robbing. Please accept my apologies. However, I don't mind situations with one winner or one loser, as a higher bet means higher risk and I would want to reward it more. I will use the other answer because it suits my expectations from the game better, but I find your answer useful and someone else with a similar problem may want to implement it.